# How to remove index.php?route=extension/module/ and make SEO friendly URL for custom controller in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

I have made my custom extension in **opencart 3.0.2.0**

But my front page open with index.php?route=extension/module/

which I do not like and want to make SEO friendly URL.

can anybody tell me what code I should add in my controller or provide any good documentation link to solve my problem?

Comment: are you using PHP ?

Comment: Yes..It is on PHP language.

Comment: @vijayrami I know it's not a solution but generally, we don't get extension/module/ directly from URL. That's why we don't make SEO friendly URL for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Login to your Administrator account. 
2- Go to: **Design** -> **SEO URL**  
3- Click on the "Add" button on the top right corner  
4- In the query field, type in: extension/module/[*your-module-name*]  
5- In the Keyword field, type the SEO keywords you want 
6- Click "Save".  
7- Repeat that for every language and store you have.